# How to use isLetter on scala arguments from main method?

Tags: scala

I am new to scala, I am trying to write a function that checks if an argument is a letter and, if it is, prints out the letter.
This doesn't work, I get the error message "value isLetter is not a member of String"

```
object printLetters{
    def main(args: Array[String]):Unit ={
        if(args.length == 0 || args.length == 1){
            println("Please provide two arguments");
        }
        if(args.length > 2){
            println("Too many arguments")
        }
        if(args(0).isLetter){
            println("It is a letter");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed `isLetter` is not a member of `String` but of `Char`. What you need to do is to check if it's indeed a single letter, and get the `Char` at the first position, like this:

```
val word = "foo"
val notLetter = ":"
val letter = "f"

def isLetter(input: String) =
  input.length == 1 && input.charAt(0).isLetter

isLetter(word) // false
isLetter(notLetter) // false
isLetter(letter) // true
```